# Função recursiva em Python que retorne o maior e o menor valor dentro de uma lista

Tags: python, recursão

Alguém poderia me ajudar com uma luz? Consigo fazer a função recursiva para achar o menor valor numa lista, e o maior valor separadamente. Mas uma função retornando os dois juntos não consigo.

O exercício seria:
Escreva uma função, chamada minmax, que recebe uma lista e retorna uma TUPLA
contendo o elemento mínimo e o elemento máximo da lista.
Sua função deve ser recursiva.

Não use o comando "max" ou "min" do Python sobre lista.
EXEMPLOS:

```
minmax([1,2,3]) = (1, 3)
minmax([49, 1, 6, 10]) = (1, 49)
```

Meu codigo:

```
def minmax(lista):

    if(len(lista) == 0):
        raise ValueError('Cannot find the maximum of an empty list.')

    if len(lista) == 1:
        return (lista[0], lista[0])
    else:
        maxValue = minmax(lista[1:])
```

Comment: Chegou a tentar fazer retornando os dois valores? Qual foi o resultado obtido?

Comment: ele retorna ValueError('Cannot find the maximum of an empty list.')

Comment: Então posta o código na pergunta e vemos o que podemos fazer.

Comment: Beleza, já coloquei!

Comment: poderia fazer primeiro o sort e depois pegar no primeiro e último valor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você chegou muito perto da solução. Faltou somente retornar quando a quantidade de números na lista é maior que 1. Você calcula o mínimo e o máximo do restante da lista, mas não faz nada com o resultado. A ideia aqui é você comparar o mínimo e o máximo que você obteve do resto da lista com o primeiro número da lista, pois este pode ser menor que o mínimo ou maior que o máximo, assim ficaria:

```
def minmax(lista):

    if(len(lista) == 0):
        raise ValueError('Cannot find the maximum of an empty list.')

    if len(lista) == 1:
        return (lista[0], lista[0])

    _min, _max = minmax(lista[1:])

    if lista[0] < _min:
        _min = lista[0]

    if lista[0] > _max:
        _max = lista[0]

    return (_min, _max)
```

Desta forma você estará calculando de forma recursiva e obterá os resultados corretos.

Comment: Nossa, muito obrigada! Agora eu consegui entender, faltou a comparação ne?! obrigada!!!